# How to draw lines on the screen for an iOS game

Tags: ios

I am working on a game where I need to draw a bunch of lines to create a wireframe sort of object, I can do this in sprite kit using nodes but adding a bunch of nodes to the screen will drop the frame rate down a lot. I don't know how to use OpenGL Es at all so that's not an option for me. Is there anything that would just allow me to draw lines on the screen in Sprite kit without adding nodes or is there another framework that will allow me to do that?

Comment: `"I don't know how to use OpenGL Es at all so that's not an option for me."` - I never consider this sort of phrase to be acceptable for me to speak myself, or to hear from my coworkers.  Are you entirely incapable of learning?

Comment: I am still in high school and I don't really get the math behind OpenGL programming. I have looked for tutorials that that thoroughly explain what is actually happening but I cannot find any. Do you know of anywhere that I can find a good tutorial? I have searched for quite some time but can't find anything that great

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 3D wireframe then your choices are sprite kit (which is built on top of OpenGL), OpenGL, or Metal. Or I guess you could use somebody's 3rd party framework that is also built on top of OpenGL or Metal.

I tend to agree with nhgrif's comment that you're "I don't know xyz so I can't do that" is needlessly limiting. If you can't do anything that involves learning new APIs then you're never going to get very far as a developer.

Comment: In Sprite kit the only way I could find to draw a line was to make a shapenode, and adding a lot of nodes will drop the frame rate. In Java the way I used to do things was to Make a jframe, override the paint method with whatever lines or shapes I wanted to draw, and refreshed it over and over again. Is there any way to do that sort of thing on iOS?